# Code from fiddle not working on site at all

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fiddle

None of the code from W3Schools and other sources work the way they should on my site.

For example, I copied the code from W3Schools and essentially just pasted it into WordPress. I used my own images and put a black border around the div to visualize it better. I also got rid of the buttons and just put the `onclick="plusDivs(-1)"` function on the div itself so clicking anywhere makes it scroll to the next image. But otherwise, the code is exactly the same. Here's a [link](http://nalawebdev.com/new/).

I don't know why it shows all the images to begin with or why the images shift downwards with each click when the same code works fine on W3Schools.

Another problem is the [popup function](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_popup) which also doesn't work on WordPress. The text of the popup message is already displayed. Clicking anything does nothing even though the cursor changes when hovering over the text. Link: http://nalawebdev.com/pop-up-doesnt-work

Any help on why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please include the relevant relevant code in a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** so that we can see whats happening and why it might not be working.

Comment: Not what you're asking, but note that if a click handler on a div is the only trigger for scrolling to the next image then your page is unusable for anybody who doesn't (or can't) use a mouse or other pointing device. You should provide a way for a keyboard-only user to access the same functionality.

Comment: Here is the code I am using:

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColors: ['#f2f2f2', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE'],
    navigation: true,
    scrollOverflow: false,
    afterRender: function(autoplay) {
      setInterval(function() {
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSection();
      }, 1500);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.section {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: helvetica, arial;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel+Decorative" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wp-admin/css/jquery.fullPage.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/wp-admin/js/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/wp-admin/js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:black;">
  <div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
      <div id="video-overlay">
        <video id="video-background" loop="" muted="" data-autoplay="" src="http://nalawebdev.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Free-Motion-Background-Golden-Light.mp4">
</video>
        <img id="logo" src="http://nalawebdev.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/logowhite.png" />
        <h1>N a l a</h1>
        <h6>Web Design & &nbsp;Development<img id="gif" src="http://nalawebdev.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/scrolldown-1.gif" /></h6>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section" style="background-color:black;">
      <div class="slidetest">[ngg_images source="galleries" container_ids="7" display_type="photocrati-nextgen_basic_slideshow" gallery_width="1000" gallery_height="500" cycle_effect="fade" cycle_interval="0" show_thumbnail_link="0" thumbnail_link_text="&#91;Show thumbnails&#93;"
        order_by="sortorder" order_direction="ASC" returns="included" maximum_entity_count="500"]</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section" style="background-color:black;">
      <div class="slidetest">[ngg_images source="galleries" container_ids="8" display_type="photocrati-nextgen_basic_slideshow" gallery_width="1000" gallery_height="500" cycle_effect="fade" cycle_interval="0" show_thumbnail_link="0" thumbnail_link_text="&#91;Show thumbnails&#93;"
        order_by="sortorder" order_direction="ASC" returns="included" maximum_entity_count="500"]</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section" style="background-color:black;">
      <div class="slidetest">[ngg_images source="galleries" container_ids="9" display_type="photocrati-nextgen_basic_slideshow" gallery_width="1000" gallery_height="500" cycle_effect="fade" cycle_interval="0" show_thumbnail_link="0" thumbnail_link_text="&#91;Show thumbnails&#93;"
        order_by="sortorder" order_direction="ASC" returns="included" maximum_entity_count="500"]</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section" style="background-color:black;">
      <div class="slidetest">[ngg_images source="galleries" container_ids="10" display_type="photocrati-nextgen_basic_slideshow" gallery_width="1000" gallery_height="500" cycle_effect="fade" cycle_interval="0" show_thumbnail_link="0" thumbnail_link_text="&#91;Show thumbnails&#93;"
        order_by="sortorder" order_direction="ASC" returns="included" maximum_entity_count="500"]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" style="background-color:black;"></div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here is my code^^ also was wondering if you guys could tell me why, when I want to add some text onm top of all the elements it does  not work even when using position and z-index? Thanks!